# Fail on running first react-native application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I started to learn react-native and i fall even at running application.
Here's my error log.

Hope that someone will help me.

> The development server returned response error code: 500
>
> URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false
>
> Body:
>   {"originModulePath":"/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/index.js","targetModuleName":"@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault","message":"Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:209:1301)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:238:485)\n    at Object.resolve (/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:180:25)\n    at dependencies.map.result (/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:311:29)\n    at Array.map ()\n    at resolveDependencies (/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:307:16)\n    at /Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:164:33\n    at Generator.next ()\n    at step (/Users/danplaton4/Desktop/react/v01/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:266:307)"}
>   processBundleResult
>       BundleDownloader.java:296
>   access$200
>       BundleDownloader.java:37
>   onResponse
>       BundleDownloader.java:174
>   execute
>       RealCall.java:153
>   run
>       NamedRunnable.java:32
>   runWorker
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162
>   run
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636
>   run
>       Thread.java:764

Comment: some new bug, just add `@babel/runtime` as a dev dependency to your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
# Clean cache 
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all 
# Start Metro Bundler directly 
react-native start 
# Run react-native run-android or run-ios in a different terminal window.`
```

Comment: Did this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

you should start project like this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and at the end you should run 
`react-native run-android` . remember that your emulator is running and android-sdk and android-jdk is already installed.

.

Comment: everything is installed, not it is the problem.